# C: Syntax error in code

Tags: c, syntax-error

#### Code:

```
//program starts here
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float e, d, m;  //declarando variables

    printf("?Cual es tu edad?\n");
    scanf("%d",&e);
    if (e<=12)
    {
        printf("El costo de su taquilla es 4.00$.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (e>65)
    {
        printf("El costo de su taquilla es 4.25$.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else if () //Line 20
    {
        printf("Hoy es: \n 1 lunes o martes \n 2 miercoles \n 3 jueves-domingo \n");
        scanf("%d",&d);
        if (d==3)
        {
            printf("El costo de su taquilla es 6.50$.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Usted es: \n 1 Dama \n 2 Estudiante \n 3 Ninguno de los anteriores \n");
            scanf("%d",&m);
            if (m==3)
            {
                printf("El costo de su taquila es 6.50$.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else if (d==2 &&m==1)
            {
                printf("El costo de su taquilla es 4.50$.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else if (d==1 &&m==2)
            {
                printf("El costo de su quilla es 4.75$\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
}//Line 49
```

#### Errors:

It says at line 20: "error: expected expression before ")" token
It says at line 49: "error: expected declaration or statement at end of input"

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty `if`:

```
else if () //Line 20
```

That's not valid C, there must be a condition inside the parentheses.

If you want to execute that branch if no other `if` was true, you should just use an `else`, not an `else if`.

The second error is due to a missing `}`, you can easily see that when looking at the indented braces.

Comment: @ArielSilvaTroche you're missing a closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

At line 20, change `else if ()` to `else`. empty `if()` should not be valid and not required.

<del>Once you remove this, other error should be gone. too.</del>

Missed due to lack of indentation, supposedly at line 50, you need to have a closing `}`, matching the opening one after `main()`. Also, you may want to add a `return` statement, it's a good practice.

If you see, the syntax of `if` condition is [Chapter 6.8.4.1, `C99` standard]

```
if ( expression ) statement
```

and the definition of *expression* is [from chapter 6.5, paragraph 1, `C99`]

> An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies computation of a value, or that designates an object or a function, or that generates side effects, or that performs a combination thereof.

so, () is not considered as a *valid* expression and hence the error.

Comment: and why's the downvote? CAn anyone please explain so that I can correct/ improve my answer/ concept? Thank you.